# Big endian in python

Tags: python-3.x, endianness

Any help with the following python trickery - UTF-8 encoded, 4 bytes big endian keywords without terminating bit.  The number of keywords is N, which equals to 2 bytes . Total for the file are 24bytes . Output is a sorted list file , one word per line, no duplicates. Ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please go through all these links: [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [how to good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).